# fgets function doesn't work

Tags: c, printf, microcontroller, fgets, scanf

When I write the following code. Putty prints the text but I can't type anything below ..

For example :

First he does a `printf` --> who are you ?

Then I do a `fgets` where I normally most type something , that doensn't work.

At last he does another `printf` where he say ; good to meet you ...

```
 int main(void)
{       
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  char name[10];
  printf("Who are you? \n");
  fgets(name,10,stdin);
  printf("Good to meet you, %s.\n",name);
  return(0);  
}
```

can anyone help me ?
thanks !

Comment: You are using `fgets` (not `fgetc` as the title suggests)

Comment: Do you have any other input statement before this fgets?

Comment: What platform, which compiler, which standard library?

Comment: i use the program keil vision and i use the libary stdio.h.And no i have no other input statements before the fgets

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run a program on some kind of microcontroller. Without knowing what it is and what programming environment you are using, it is impossible to tell what's goung on, and then your chances would be much greater if you find a support forum for your specific microcontroller and programming environment.

Comment: You doesn't use the library `stdio.h`. That file is a header file that define an interface to your run-time library. But the library is .a or .lib file that contains the implementation of the interface defined in `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 0):

You have overwritten the implemnetation of `fputs` in your source code. So your linker doesn't need to lookup the library implementation of that function. With your implementation of `fputc` you have connected the stdio-output-path to your UART transmitter.

You need to define the corresponding input-path. This could be done by implementing a fgetc function. In that can the library function `fgets` can call your function, polling the UART receiver.

The default implementation of stdio in embedded environment is highly vendor dependent. It can be connected to

- the JTAG debugger
- the microcontroller specific debug/console ports
- nothing.

Therefore you are responsible to make the right implemantation of that connection. This can be more complecated than the `fputc` implementation because you have to check, if there is data received at the UART at the time of call.

Comment: i don't now what you mean .. What must i chance in my code ?